# Creating php script to retrive value from database which is close to user value if exact value not found

Tags: php

I want to find a value entered by user from my database. If the value is found show the value but if the value is not found it must show a value which is close to the value entered by user.

I have to write code to find value which exist but am unable to write for the value which is not found.

To show close value:

```
$j=0; $l=0; $res=[]; 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $id=$_POST['text']; 
    $t=rtrim($id); 
    $word=explode(" ",$t); 
    $count=count($word); 
    for ($i = 0; $i <$count ; $i++) { 
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM school WHERE roman='$word[$i]' OR roman1='$word[$i]' OR roman2='$word[$i]' LIMIT 1"); 
        if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) { 
            while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
                $re=$re.$r['arabic'] . '&nbsp;'; $res[$j]=$r['arabic']; 
            } 
        } else { 
            $re=$re.$word[$i].'&nbsp;'; 
            $res[$j]=mb_convert_encoding($word[$i], "UTF-8"); 
        } 
        $j++;
```

Comment: Please show your code and include any errors you are getting.

Comment: $j=0;
$l=0;
$res=[];



if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$id=$_POST['text'];
$t=rtrim($id);
$word=explode(" ",$t);

$count=count($word);
for($i = 0; $i <$count  ; $i++) {



 $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM school WHERE roman='$word[$i]' OR roman1='$word[$i]' OR roman2='$word[$i]'  LIMIT 1");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$re=$re.$r['arabic'] . '&nbsp;';
 $res[$j]=$r['arabic'];
}
}
else{
$re=$re.$word[$i].'&nbsp;';
$res[$j]=mb_convert_encoding($word[$i], "UTF-8");

}


$j++;
i

Comment: please give me just idea do not write code just tell me how can i find value which is close to value which user enter if value not found in database

Comment: Then see my answer, I have given you all the information you need.

Comment: BTW, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: There does not appear to be any JavaScript involved here.

Comment: @shrayarai you still haven't accepted an answer. Did you resolve your issue or do you still require help?

Comment: i have done it by wildcard but results are not accurate so i am trying compare character by character string . so value most near to uservalue could be found

Answer (score 1):

When you're this new to PHP (or any language), I think it's important for you to experiment and discover on your own. And you haven't provided any details about your exact situation. But hopefully this can help point you in the right direction:

- First, make a query to the database.
- If the query returns more than 0
  results, proceed normally.
- If the query returns 0 results, repeat the
  query, slightly modified to use `WHERE LIKE` rather than `WHERE =`.

MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/examples.html

LIKE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Pattern Matching: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

The above assumes you have a MySQL database. As I said, you haven't provided many details.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting from your database, you can use the `LIKE` expression. Alternatively you can use REGEXP. To find values close to the input value.

You can read more about the two above here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/retrieving-data.html

You should consider using mysqli functions instead of mysql functions. The reason being that mysql functions are deprecated and as of php7 completely removed, because of security issues.

Mysqli is more secure, and you can use prepared statements. You can read more about mysqli here:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

The "%" sign is used to define wildcards (missing letters) both before and after the pattern. 
SQL Like: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: You're right. Just bringing attention to the wildcard.